# Is there different behaviour of `std::fstream` and `std::stringstream` in read-write-usage?

Tags: c++, iostream

I tried the following to overwrite a stream "in place":

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

void e(std::iostream &s) {
    unsigned char c;
    while (s) {
        s.get(reinterpret_cast<char &>(c));
        ++c;
        s.put(reinterpret_cast<char &>(c));
    }
}

int main() {
    // test for `stringstream`
    std::stringstream s("test");
    e(s);
    std::cout << s.str() << std::endl;

    // setup temporary file
    auto n = std::tmpnam(nullptr);
    {
        std::ofstream f(n);
        f << "test";
    }
    // test for `fstream`
    {
        std::fstream f(n);
        e(f);
    }
    {
        std::string buf;
        std::ifstream f(n);
        f >> buf;
        std::cout << buf << std::endl;
    }
}
```

To my surprise, this outputs (see https://godbolt.org/z/qa881v78q)

```
uftu
tust
```

The `stringstream` is overwritten as expected, while the file content changed in just one place. The `get` seems to have change the write position, and for some reason the stream went bad after that.

I'd guess I'm missing something very basic here, but I'd really like to use a `stringstream` as a simple mock for a `fstream`, as both are `iostream`s.

Answer (score 3):

A string stream has 1 data buffer, but has separate read/write positions into that buffer.

A file stream has only has 1 read/write position into its data.  When you read from or write to a file, that position is advanced by the number of bytes that were read/written.

To do what you are attempting, you would have to seek the write position back to the previous position after each read in order to overwrite the character that you just read.

Comment: Ok, what is the actual suggestion? Adding `auto pos = s.tellg();` before reading and `s.seekp(pos);` afterwards seems to work (see https://godbolt.org/z/jh3MdjWda). Can it be done more cleverly?

Comment: @mkluwe that's basically what you need to do. You could try `s.seekp(-1, std::ios_base::cur)` but that will work only for file streams with a shared read/write position, not for other streams with separate read/write positions.